# How can I smooth out the edges in my object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I wanted to make my own keychain as a project for school, I am also almost finished but when trying to bevel the outer edges there are multiple faces ontop of eachother on the part I extruded at the top.

I have used the bevel modifier before but in this case it won't work properly and I can't make the circle part first because then the edge between the two parts won't be smooth or it won't work at all.

I drew what I want to make poorly on the pictures below. The things I marked in the first picture is the bevel and the hole I haven't added yet and on the second picture I marked where I want to bevel it.

Any help and tips on how I can smooth the edges are appreciated!

Thank you in advance!

[image: top view]

[image: side view]

Comment: Hello, I'm not sure what you mean, are you trying to achieve the first shape (with the drawn corrections)? Maybe share your file so that we can try?

Comment: Hello, yes I'm trying to get the shape of the first picture, and want to smooth the edges I marked in the second picture.

Comment: you need to delete some faces, and in order to smooth the edges, bevel them?

Comment: I used the bevel modifier, so you say I just need to manually delete the not needed faces?

Comment: Yes but maybe share your file?

Comment: sure here it is: https://www.mediafire.com/file/110m6uz45y7l0sh/SA_BITCOIN.blend/file

Comment: is it what you're trying to achieve? https://zupimages.net/up/23/26/37y2.jpg

Comment: sort of but beveled so its smoother

Comment: like that? https://zupimages.net/up/23/26/e1dk.jpg

Comment: the edges are fine but I'm talking about the flat side to be beveld

Comment: do you have a reference image? it would help